Redhat RHE9 ansible raising Invalid repo ID while the repo is listed on the system
I'm running Linux Redhat 9 on one of my AWS EC2 and I'm trying to install OpenVPN server.
For that I want to enable codeready-builder repository.
Here is the ansible task that enable the repo :
15 - name: Enable extra repos for RHEL 9
16   rhsm_repository:
17     name: "codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-{{ ansible_architecture }}-rpms"
18     state: enabled
19   when: ansible_distribution=="RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == "9"

and it throws the error below :

I connected to the target system and run dnf repolist --all, and I got this

So I thought the problem was really in the repo id, so I modified the task and change codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-{{ ansible_architecture }}-rpms to codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-rhui-rpms this :
15 - name: Enable extra repos for RHEL 9
16   rhsm_repository:
17     name: "codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-rhui-rpms"
18     state: enabled
19   when: ansible_distribution=="RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == "9"

But I still get the error :

Also when I try to enable the repository directly on the target host, it gives this :

So I really don't understand where the problem is. Am I missing any useful step there?
